# Changing one value in nested array changes all values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a `10x10` array filled with `0` values, which I though I could do like this:

```js
var myArray = new Array(10).fill(new Array(10).fill(0));
```

This is working fine, but there's a problem when I try to change one of the values in the array, for example:

```js
myArray[2][3] = 6;
```

Instead of changing just the one value, the output is this:

```
0 [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] (10)
1 [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] (10)
2 [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] (10)
3 [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] (10)
4 [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] (10)
5 [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] (10)
6 [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] (10)
7 [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] (10)
8 [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] (10)
9 [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] (10)
```

As you can see, all values in the column with index `3` have been changed. Why is this, and how do I create a new, zero-filled array without this happening?

```js
var myArray = new Array(10).fill(new Array(10).fill(0));

console.log("--------Before--------");
console.log(myArray);

myArray[2][3] = 6;

console.log("--------After---------");
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: `.fill()` does not create a new array for every slot in the array it is called on. There's just one `new Array(10).fill(0)`. Use `Array.from()` and its second parameter (a callback).

Comment: `fill` fills with a constant value, this is for objects the same object reference.

Comment: `new Array(10).fill(null).map(() => new Array(10).fill(0))` will create a new Array for each row (`map` executes a callback for each element, while `fill` does not)

Comment: @blex `Array.from({length: 10}, () => new Array(10).fill(0))`

Comment: @Andreas nice one